# ¿Cómo se calcula un cuatrimestre?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo una página en la cual se ingresa información de forma trimestral, el detalle surge que eso se tiene que hacer al cierre del trimestre, por lo cual al culminar los 3 meses correspondientes la información que se muestra para cada trimestre se deja de visualizar y lo que yo quiero es que en lugar de tres meses sean cuatro meses.

```
//calculando el trimestre, el numero de trimestre del anio
    $mes = date("m",strtotime($hoy));
    $mes = is_null($mes) ? date('m') : $mes;
    $trim=floor(($mes-1) / 3)+1;

    if ($trim == 1)
    {
    $trimestre_nombre = "Q-3";//abril-mayo-junio
    }

    else if ($trim == 2)
    {
    $trimestre_nombre = "Q-4";//enero-febrero-marzo
    }

    else if ($trim == 3)
    {
    $trimestre_nombre = "Q-1";//julio-agosto-septiembre
    }

    else if ($trim == 4)
    {
    $trimestre_nombre = "Q-2";//octubre-noviembre-diciembre
    }
```

Hasta ahora en cuanto al cálculo de trimestre he encontrado éste, y funciona.

Cuando en lugar de 3 lo divido entre 4 funciona para el primer trimestre que va desde julio-agosto-septiembre y se extiende a octubre, pero luego los calcula como trimestres.

Comment: Comenta el código lo máximo posible. Yo al menos no termino de comprender lo que hace tu código. `$trim=floor(($mes-1) / 3)+1;` y `"Q-3"` etc

Comment: Simplemente básate en el mes para determinar en que cuatrimestre se encuentra, en lugar de realizar la operación esa. Si el mes se encuentra entre X e Y pues tal cuatrimestre...

Comment: Lo que hace el if elseif es que atravez de el guarda la informacion, y de esa forma se muestra, pero al culminar el trimestre se hace un recuento de la información y durante ese mes en este caso digamos octubre durante ese mes se tiene que meter información del trimestre 1 que ya paso para que luego al empezar el segundo trimestre en el mes de noviembre no se visualiza mas información.